# Android button text moves

Tags: android, layout, button, text

Ive got the problem that, when i click one of the buttons shown in xml below, the text on the button jumps down one line. So if the button is 1 line, no text is shown. If the button is 2 lines, only the first line is shown, in the buttom of the button.

Nothing in the onClick method changes the layout.

Heres the XML

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">


    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"  >

.. a few other layouts and controls that works fine 



        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout276"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/TableRow10"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >



                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/BtnRet"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Ret"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />      

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/BtnVisningsType"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Decimaltal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/BtnFunktioner"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Funktioner"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18dp" />      
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

.. a few other layouts and controls that works fine


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now, if i change the layout_width on the buttons to wrap_content, it all works fine (got the idea from [When changing textview, the text on a button below the textview moves down. Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047987/when-changing-textview-the-text-on-a-button-below-the-textview-moves-down-help) )  - except the buttons now obviusly dont have the same width, and it looks messy.

Does anyone have any idea why this happens, and how i can both keep the text, and decide the size of the buttons?

Answer (score 2):

This adds complexity to the layout but might be a solution.

Add a LinearLayout to your table row and use weights to control precise layout of your buttons.  Something like this:

```
<TableRow
                android:id="@+id/TableRow10"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:weightSum="3"
                  android:orientation="horizantal"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BtnRet"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Ret"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />      

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BtnVisningsType"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Decimaltal"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/BtnFunktioner"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Funktioner"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />      

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

Caveats:

- Might give a performance hit
- Typed from memory, please excuse any typos
- Not tested
- use padding/margin to adjust precise sizing

A RelativeLayout might also work.

Comment: Completely agree with this. You want to try and avoid hard coded view dimensions e.g. android:layout_width="120dp"

Comment: Ive got a few questions to this. First: Your suggestion is a linearlayout, inside the tableview ive already got? If the linearlayout with the line "weigthsum" can adjust the buttons to be next to each other instead of under - doesnt that kind of ruin the point of the tablelayout?

Comment: Second: If i use padding/margin to adjust size of buttons, wont the size of the button change, if i change the text on it? I would like the buttons to be the same size as each other, and stay that size no matter what happens. (of course, if the text gets to long it will go a second line couse of the wrap_content height, but thats fine.)

Comment: If you want the buttons under each other, sorry, I missed this requirement, this gets more complex, especially if you change the text in code.  Please confirm that this is what you want to do.

Comment: You must have misunderstood; I want the buttons NEXT to each other, on the same line.

Comment: Using your code, after the click, the ending of the longer texts disappears. The first one "Ret", gets adjusted left.

Comment: Keeping the code i have, with layout_width set to wrap_content instead of 120dp works fine. Adjusting the size of buttons with padding also works fine. But this way, if the text changes, the size of the button changes too. Why is it that you should avoid hard coded lines like width 120dp?

Comment: One or more of use is confused :)  Your first comment, "Your suggestion is a linearlayout, inside the tableview ive already got".  No, I suggest putting it into the TableRow.  I'm assuming that you want rows of 3 buttons in your TableLayout.  Your table is vertical since it inherits from the parent layout.  Please confirm 2 things.  That you want rows of 3 buttons, horizantally arranged in a vertical TableLayout and are you changing the text of the buttons in code?

Comment: Yes, i want the 3 buttons on 1 row. And no, i do not change the text, but i would like that option later on. For instance, if the app has to translate to another language.

Comment: Sorry, been away for a while.  What I suggest should work fine and I'm baffled as to how a button can even move within this layout, let alone the issue with the text moving.  I suggest that you start a new question with the full layout XML as you have it now.  Good luck.